# Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE - Micrometer - KafkaMetrics - Failed to bind meter logs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

I am using `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint for its `kafka_consumer_*` metrics. Upgrading from `Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE` to `2.3.2.RELEASE`, is showing me **a lot** of these "extra" logs - whenever there is a failure to bind:

> INFO
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$checkAndBindMetrics$1[173]
> -- Failed to bind meter: kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.[metric1]...However, this could happen and
> might be restored in the next refresh.
>  INFO
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$checkAndBindMetrics$1[173]
> -- Failed to bind meter: kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.[metric2]...However, this could happen and
> might be restored in the next refresh.
>  INFO
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$checkAndBindMetrics$1[173]
> -- Failed to bind meter: kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.[metric3]...However, this could happen and
> might be restored in the next refresh.
>  INFO
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics.lambda$checkAndBindMetrics$1[173]
> -- Failed to bind meter: kafka.consumer.fetch.manager.[metric4]...However, this could happen and
> might be restored in the next refresh.

It is an `INFO` log level with the somewhat *reassuring* ending words of `However, this could happen and might be restored in the next refresh.`, therefore, not meant to be alarming, but what is its purpose for showing it in this upgrade?

In the meantime, i have *suppressed* them(the extra logs) with:
`logging.level.io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics=WARN`

Comment: I can observe the same messages

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. I "fixed" mine by refining a `MeterFilter` that appears to have broken when upgrading from 1.3.2 to 1.5.4. See https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2256 for more details. Best I could provide is that if you can reliably reproduce this locally then try break pointing on the `if` block in https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaMetrics.java#L195-L204

In IntelliJ use "find class" of `io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaMetrics`

e.g.: `if (message != null && message.contains("Prometheus requires")) {`

And then read what the actual `message` is. My error turned out to be:

> Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys. There is already an existing meter named 'kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_bytes_consumed_total' containing tag keys [client_id, env, instance, kafka_version, spring_id]. The meter you are attempting to register has keys [client_id, env, instance, kafka_version, spring_id, topic].

Comment: This should be fixed in 1.6 according to the issue you linked.